# How to get string data from port netbeans?

Tags: java, android, netbeans, port

I'm making a cross-platform project, where user is an Android app, and server is a NetBeans project. User is sending some simple string messages to port 8080 of my PC, using it's IP, like this :

```
 try {
                Log.d("LAB", "RED sent");
                String str = "User1.RED";
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println(str);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
String str = "User1.RED";
```

But I can't find a way to read these strings in my Server!
I am new to NetBeans, and i couldn't find any help in internet.

Comment: Sorry for double written 'String str = "User1.RED";'

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html